# Faceebook Fetch Friends Graph API

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in which i have to integrate login via facebook, Signup via Facebook, and Fetch friends.For that i had create an app on developer.facebook.com then generate an Facebook APP ID. I am using Facebook-IOS framework. I am able to get Profile information. But during fetching friend i was getting error. After a hard study i know about the facebook permission. I set 'User-Friends" as permission, But now it is giving only one friend the response is as follow..

data = (
    One Friend information
);
paging =     {
    next = "https://graph.facebook.com/{MY_USER_ID}/home?format=json&access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}&limit=25&until=................";
    ;
};

I have done so much change now frustrated with this Problem. so Please some one guide me where i am wrong. If i have to set some setting on facebook app created on developer app than please guide me. Please help me out from this horrible problem.

Comment: What code did you used for fetching friends from FB ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" 
                                 andParams:[ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,link,gender,last_name,first_name",@"fields",nil]
                               andDelegate:self];
```